# Instantiate Actor System for my code design

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-cluster

I am refactoring akka code and ended up in a situation where I am not able to instantiate the actors in the actor system

I have a BaseActor which has all the common functionality used by my other actors

```
trait baseActor extends Actor with timeout {
  implicit val system = context.system
  implicit val dispatcher = system.dispatchers.lookup("myCustomDispatcher")
  implicit val ldapService = ldapSerice
}
```

I have also a Person Service to do mostly CRUD operations on Ldap

```
trait PersonService {
  def addUser(user:User)(implicit ldapSerice:Ldapservice) = ???
  def getUser(uuid:String)(implicit ldapSerice:Ldapservice): User = ???
}
```

but uses the ldapservice implicitly, assume that I need this ldap service to make ldap connecting and calls, As some other developer has implemented it so I have to follow the same pattern

While I am trying to instantiate the actor system from the Main class I am not sure how to pass that actor system to the base actor. so all the child actors created can use that

```
object Main extends App {
   val system = ActorSystem(config.settings.getString("systemName"))
   val myActor = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor],"MyActor")
}
```

My actor

```
class myactor extends baseActor with PersonService{
  overide def receive: Unit = {
    case "create" => addUser
    case "delete" => //my business logic
  }
}
```

While it does not throw any compilations errors during the run time it is throws exception not able to create actor because of dispatcher is not configured but however I can see in the configuration file It is here.

[image]

```
hostName = "localhost"

//get the data from environment variable
//hostName = {?HOST_NAME} //If environment variable exist pick that value or override

akka {
    #loggers = ["akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger"]
    loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    loglevel = "DEBUG"
    logging-filter="akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"

    debug {
        receive = on
        lifecycle = on
        event-stream = on
    }
}

clusterLdap {
    version = 10
    name = "MyApplication"
    ldap {
        hostName = ""
        port = 20681
        bindDN = ""
        password = ""
        name = ""
        permissions = ["read","write","bind"]
    }
}
akka {
    provider = "cluster"
    wfm-dispatcher = {
        type = dispatcher
        executor = "fork-join-executor"
        fork-join-executor {
            parallelism-min = 4
            parallelism-factor = 2.0
            parallelism-max = 8
        }
    }
    remote {
        netty.tcp {
            hostName = "localhost"
            port = 2022
        }
    }
    
    cluster {
     seedNodes = ["akka.tcp://MyCluster@localhost:2541"]
     roles = ["service"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the configuration file in the question.

Comment: Is the line of code `system.dispatchers.lookup("myCustomDispatcher")` actually `system.dispatchers.lookup("wfm-dispatcher")` in your real code? It's best to post real code rather than made up examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Akka Documentation on Classic Dispatchers](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/dispatchers.html), it notes:

> The dispatcher you specify in `withDispatcher` and the `dispatcher` property in the deployment configuration is in fact a path into your configuration. So in this example it’s a top-level section, but you could for instance put it as a sub-section, where you’d use periods to denote sub-sections, like this: `"foo.bar.my-dispatcher"`

In the configuration above, the dispatcher path is `"akka.wfm-dispatcher"`, so that's the string you'll need to use to look it up. Alternatively, you can put the dispatcher configuration at the top level rather than inside the `akka` section, and look it up as `"wfm-dispatcher"`.

Also note that the code above won't actually use your custom dispatcher to run these actors. To configure the actor to run with your dispatcher (assuming the configuration file is unchanged), you can use:

```
system.actorOf(Props[MyActor].withDispatcher("akka.wfm-dispatcher"),"MyActor")
```